# Appcelerator Alloy model binding failing with instance model

Tags: model-view-controller, appcelerator, model-binding, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

controller:

```
var args=arguments[0]||{};
if(args.model){
    $.myFighter = args.model;   

}else{
    alert('data not passed');
}
```

View:

```
<Alloy>
    <Model id="myFighter" src="fighters" instance="true"/>
    <Window>        
        <ScrollView layout="vertical">
            <View layout="vertical">
                <Label id="name" text="{$.myFighter.name}"/>
                <Label id="nickname" text="{$.myFighter.nickname}"/>
                <Label id="fighterId" text="{$.myFighter.id}"/>
            </View>>
        </ScrollView>>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Yet the text is always empty in my view, like if model was never assigned.

The controller is called from another controller, passing the model as an argument like this:

```
var win=Alloy.createController('detail',{model:detailObj});
win.getView().open();
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I do it right?

Comment: Data binding should be used on a collection, not with a single model like that, check here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding

Comment: I only want to show data from a single model not a collection, before this i have already a table with data binding and a collection, but this is after clicking on a row i want to show the "details" of that row, sending the single instance to the view instead of having to hardcode all the parameters in the controller and assign it with an id. Im sure this is possible because there is a "hacky" way of doing it, but im looking for the correct way.

Comment: @asiviero you are incorrect, you can bind a single model to a view see example here https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/test/apps/models/binding_no_persistence